# Finding the row index of a clicked button in table cell

Tags: java, swt

The last column of my table is populated with a button.  When the user clicks on the button, I want to open a file that is also in the same row as the button.

[image]

Here is the column code for the button.

```
 case 6:
               Map<Object, Button> buttons = new HashMap<Object, Button>();   
               TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
               Button button;
               if(buttons.containsKey(cell.getElement())) {
                  button = buttons.get(cell.getElement());
               }
               else
               {
                 button = new Button((Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl(),SWT.PUSH);
                 //button.setText("Adobe");
                 button.setImage(loadImage("/images/AdobeIcon.png"));

                 buttons.put(cell.getElement(), button);
               }
               TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
               editor.grabHorizontal  = true;
               editor.grabVertical = true;
               editor.setEditor(button , item, cell.getColumnIndex());
               button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new SelectionListener(item, button, cell.getElement()));
               editor.layout();
```

1. Is it possible to send the selected index to the listener class?
   If they click the first button - sends 0
   if they click the second button - send 1
2. Do I even need the TableEditor?

If that is possible, it makes the listener code easy.

This is what I am trying right in the listener code.

```
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
     AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData selected = (( AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData)element);
     int index = AplotSaveDataModel.getInstance().getIndexOf(selected);
     final File viewerFile = new File(AplotSaveDataModel.getInstance().getSelectedPDFFileName(index));
     try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(viewerFile);
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

3. Why is the code above always returning a index of 0?

***EDIT***

I am not fully understanding how to get the row index in the data of the button.

```
button.setData("row.id", rowId);
```

I am assuming that "row.id" is a key and rowId is the value.  So I will need to populate rowId with code to get the Row Index.

```
int rowId = "Some code to get the Row Index"?
```

If I wanted to get the column index, I can just do

```
int rowId = cell.getColumnIndex();
```

I can not figure out how to populate rowId to be able to get the row index/number?

Here is the code to get the column number (which is not needed)

```
 case 6:
               Map<Object, Button> buttons = new HashMap<Object, Button>();   
               TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
               Button button;
           ***int rowId = cell.getColumnIndex();***
               if(buttons.containsKey(cell.getElement())) {
                  button = buttons.get(cell.getElement());
               }
               else
               {
                 button = new Button((Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl(),SWT.PUSH);
                 //button.setText("Adobe");
                 button.setImage(loadImage("/images/AdobeIcon.png"));
              ***button.setData("row.id", rowId);***
                 buttons.put(cell.getElement(), button);
               }
               TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
               editor.grabHorizontal  = true;
               editor.grabVertical = true;
               editor.setEditor(button , item, cell.getColumnIndex());
               button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new SelectionListener(item, button, cell.getElement()));
               editor.layout();
              }
```

Listener Class

```
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
     if (event.widget instanceof Button) {
        int rowId = (Integer) event.widget.getData("row.id");
        System.out.println("Row Int " + rowId + "\n");
     }
```

Please help me get this working - It is a very important part of my project

***EDIT 2*******

```
 public class AplotPDFResultsTableViewer extends TableViewer {

 public AplotPDFResultsTableViewer(Composite parent, int style) {
  super(parent, style);
  Table table = getTable();
  GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
  table.setLayoutData(gridData);
  createColumns();
  table.setHeaderVisible(true);
  table.setLinesVisible(true);
  setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
}

public static Image loadImage(String path)
{
  Image newImage = null;
  try {
     newImage = new Image(null, AplotPDFResultsTableViewer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path));
  }
  catch(SWTException ex) {
      System.out.println("Couldn't find " + path);
      ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return newImage;
}

private void createColumns() {

  TableViewerColumn col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(150);
  col.getColumn().setText("Creation Date");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColorColumnLabelProvider());

  col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(150);
  col.getColumn().setText("ItemId");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColorColumnLabelProvider());

  col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(50);
  col.getColumn().setText("RevId");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColorColumnLabelProvider());

  col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(50);
  col.getColumn().setText("PRL");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColorColumnLabelProvider());

  col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(200);
  col.getColumn().setText("File Location");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColorColumnLabelProvider());

  col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(200);
  col.getColumn().setText("File Name");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColorColumnLabelProvider());

  col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(50);
  col.getColumn().setText("");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColorColumnLabelProvider());
}


public class ColorColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {
  @Override
  public void update(final ViewerCell cell) {

      Object element = cell.getElement();
      if(element instanceof AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData) {

         AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData p = (AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData) element;
         switch(cell.getColumnIndex()) {

            case 0:
               cell.setText(p.getDateTime());
               break;
            case 1:
               cell.setText(p.getItemId());
               break;
            case 2:
               cell.setText(p.getRevId());
               break;
            case 3:
               cell.setText(p.getPRL());
               break;
            case 4:
               //cell.setForeground(black);
               cell.setText(p.getFileDir());
               break;
            case 5:
               //cell.setForeground(black);
               cell.setText(p.getfileName());
               break;
            case 6:
               Map<Object, Button> buttons = new HashMap<Object, Button>();   
               TableItem item = (TableItem) cell.getItem();
               Button button;
               int rowId = cell.getColumnIndex();
               if(buttons.containsKey(cell.getElement())) {
                  button = buttons.get(cell.getElement());
               }
               else
               {
                 button = new Button((Composite) cell.getViewerRow().getControl(),SWT.PUSH);
                 //button.setText("Adobe");
                 button.setImage(loadImage("/images/AdobeIcon.png"));
                 button.setData("row.id", rowId);
                 buttons.put(cell.getElement(), button);
               }
               TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(item.getParent());
               editor.grabHorizontal  = true;
               editor.grabVertical = true;
               editor.setEditor(button , item, cell.getColumnIndex());
               button.addListener(SWT.Selection, new SelectionListener(item, button, cell.getElement()));
               editor.layout();
              }
          }
      }
}// End ColorColumnLabelProvider Class

// ===============================================================
//
//    SelectionListener Class
//
// ===============================================================
class SelectionListener implements Listener {
  TableItem item;
  Button editButton;
  Object element;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                         Constructor                                  //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  public SelectionListener(TableItem item, Button editButton, Object element) {
      this.item = item;
      this.editButton = editButton;
      this.element = element;
   }

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //                         handleEvent                                  //
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
     if (event.widget instanceof Button) {
        int rowId = (Integer) event.widget.getData("row.id");
        System.out.println("Row Int " + rowId + "\n");
     }
     //AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData selected = (( AplotSaveDataModel.SaveData)element);
     //int index = AplotSaveDataModel.getInstance().getIndexOf(selected);
     //final File viewerFile = new   File(AplotSaveDataModel.getInstance().getSelectedPDFFileName(index));
     //try {
     //   Desktop.getDesktop().open(viewerFile);
     //}
     //catch (IOException e) {
     //   e.printStackTrace();
    //}
  }
}// End SelectionListener Class
}  // End AplotPDFTableViewer Class
```

Comment: Can you please also add `ArrayContentProvider`

Comment: @Waqas llyas, you mean other then setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider()); that is at the top of the class?

Comment: Yes but where is the complete class of ArrayContentProvider? Is it from the API?

Comment: I think I understand.  I have a data model class that creates the array that is displayed in the table.  I have the class above that is setting up the table columns and getting values from the data model class.  The I have a dialog class that creates the table viewer to display the table.  This code is in the Dialog class.  viewer.setInput(AplotSaveDataModel.getInstance().getArrayData());

Comment: @Waqasllyas I am sorry to have extended this question out like this.  I now understand that your answer correct and very easy to incorporate.  I did not even need the row index.  I just took the file name from the element and stored in the button data.  Works Great!!!  Thank Again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each button instance you can do set a data on the widget that helps you identify which row's button was pressed. When creating the button:

```java
Button button = ...
button.setData("row.id", rowId); // Can also use row index here or something
```

You may save the file path directly as data as well. And in the listener:

```
@Override
public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    if (event.widget instanceof Button) {
        String rowId = event.widget.getData("row.id");
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: llyas  I am not having much luck figuring out how to use the setData.

Comment: What problem are you facing? Setting data on a button should be straightforward. Can you explain your problem.

Comment: I will place the code I am using in my comment above and explain what is happening

Comment: Added a Edit to the question to explain the issue I am having

Comment: Getting the row index depends a lot on how you are adding items to the tree. Are you using a tree viewer? If so then whatever object represents each row in your data could have some index which is equivalent to row index in tree. 

If you look at my answer you can see that I said that you can set any data on the button. Event the filename you want to open can also be directly set on the button. Setting a row index is not really the only option.

Comment: llyas, it is actually a tableviewer

Comment: llyas, let me include the entire class.  That may give you a better idea what I am doing.